# Drupal call to undefined function when creating user

Tags: drupal-7

I'm getting this error message when creating new user trhough **admin/people/create/**:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function feitoervas_form_validate() in /home/feitoervas/www/novo/includes/form.inc on line 1513**

I have a function **feitoervas_form_validate()** defined on template.php in **sites/all/themes/feitoervas/**, but it shoundn't be used only on theme pages? Admin theme is seven.

The error also happens if I disable the theme or even delete it. Tried to update drupal, but didn't solve the problem.
Drupal version is 7.34.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a hook like this:
    function CHANGEYOURTHEME_your_node_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
          feitoervas_form_validate();
    }
So you will validate the form only at submit.
I hope this helps.